# How do I build EmberJS app with REST-like back-end?

Tags: rest, ember.js

I've not looked into BackboneJS or EmberJS in detail, but as I understand, it is possible to have BackboneJS seamlessly work with a REST back-end.  Whereas EmberJS doesn't seem to have anything I can use out of the box.

Can anyone offer any advice how to achieve this with EmberJS?

Comment: See ember-data. It will be merged to EmberJS by 1.0 release

Comment: Cool, does this include the ability to map models from the datasource like in KnockoutJs mapping plugin?

Comment: I'd say `ember-data` is better than Knockout's `mapping` plug-in in many ways. For example, you can map relationships and *some* data types (currently `number`, `string`, `Date`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need a simple REST adapter without much complexity, then

https://github.com/cerebris/ember-rest

is great for the job.

Answer (score 0):

I've written an article about Ember.js on InfoQ, that goes through the basics. The article used Ember 0.9.5, so not everything will be working with the newest Ember 1.0-pre release.

It goes through the basic structure of an Ember-app as well as the very basics with Ember Data.

http://www.infoq.com/articles/emberjs

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for something like Ember-rails

https://github.com/emberjs/ember-rails